# Pandas: More efficient way to update a column in pandas dataframe without a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in which I want to update the value of a column based on another column in the dataframe. I was using the following code to update it before:

```
for i1, col1 in dfMod.iterrows():
if col1['day'] == "MONDAY":
    dfMod.ix[i1,'weekIndex'] = 1
elif col1['day'] == "TUESDAY":
    dfMod.ix[i1,'weekIndex'] = 2
elif col1['day'] == "WEDNESDAY":
    dfMod.ix[i1,'weekIndex'] = 3
elif col1['day'] == "THURSDAY":
    dfMod.ix[i1,'weekIndex'] = 4
elif col1['day'] == "FRIDAY":
    dfMod.ix[i1,'weekIndex'] = 5
elif col1['day'] == "SATURDAY":
    dfMod.ix[i1,'weekIndex'] = 6
else:
    dfMod.ix[i1,'weekIndex'] = 7
```

However, the dataframe has 300,000 rows and takes forever to compile. Is there a better way to update the column?

Comment: Look at the Series `map` method.

Comment: I've just recently asked this as well. My question might be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42972081/updating-columns-in-dataframe-using-a-series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict`:

```
d = {"MONDAY": 1, "TUESDAY":2, "WEDNESDAY":3, "THURSDAY":4, 
     "FRIDAY":5, "SATURDAY":6, "SUNDAY":7}

dfMod["weekIndex"] = dfMod["day"].map(d)
```

Sample:

```
dfMod = pd.DataFrame({'day':['TUESDAY','THURSDAY','FRIDAY','SATURDAY','MONDAY','SUNDAY']})

d = {"MONDAY": 1, "TUESDAY":2, "WEDNESDAY":3, 
     "THURSDAY":4, "FRIDAY":5, "SATURDAY":6, "SUNDAY":7}

dfMod["weekIndex"] = dfMod["day"].map(d)
print (dfMod)
        day  weekIndex
0   TUESDAY          2
1  THURSDAY          4
2    FRIDAY          5
3  SATURDAY          6
4    MONDAY          1
5    SUNDAY          7
```

**Timings** in `300k` - `map` is `6 times` faster as `apply` solution:

```
dfMod = pd.DataFrame({'day':['TUESDAY','THURSDAY','FRIDAY','SATURDAY','MONDAY','SUNDAY']})
#300k rows
dfMod = pd.concat([dfMod]*50000).reset_index(drop=True)

d = {"MONDAY": 1, "TUESDAY":2, "WEDNESDAY":3, "THURSDAY":4, 
     "FRIDAY":5, "SATURDAY":6, "SUNDAY":7}

In [92]: %timeit dfMod["weekIndex"] = dfMod["day"].map(d)
10 loops, best of 3: 22.7 ms per loop

In [93]: %timeit dfMod["weekIndex1"] = dfMod["day"].apply(lambda x: d[x])
10 loops, best of 3: 141 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly and as you said way faster than apply

Comment: I already test your original solution in 300k rows - `1 loop, best of 3: 21min 47s per loop`

Answer (score 2):

Try the `apply` method:

```
daysOfWeek = {"MONDAY": 1, "TUESDAY":2, "WEDNESDAY":3, "THURSDAY":4, "FRIDAY":5, "SATURDAY":6, "SUNDAY":7}

dfMod["weekIndex"] = dfMod["day"].apply(lambda x: daysOfWeek[x])
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use @jezrael's answer as it is idiomatic.
This is purely for demonstration and an attempt to provide useful information about other pandas tools that could be used.

***setup***
*using @jezrael's given example*

```
dfMod = pd.DataFrame({'day':['TUESDAY','THURSDAY','FRIDAY','SATURDAY','MONDAY','SUNDAY']})

d = {"MONDAY": 1, "TUESDAY":2, "WEDNESDAY":3, 
     "THURSDAY":4, "FRIDAY":5, "SATURDAY":6, "SUNDAY":7}
```

***alternate solution***

```
dfMod.join(pd.Series(d, name='weekIndex'), on='day')

        day  weekIndex
0   TUESDAY          2
1  THURSDAY          4
2    FRIDAY          5
3  SATURDAY          6
4    MONDAY          1
5    SUNDAY          7
```